# How to pass objects between classes using NSNotificationCenter - Fail to pass objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

My code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"1": @"_infoView3",
                       @"2": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_showSelectionView.frame.size.height]
                       };

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification"
                                           object:dict];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:@"UIKeyboardDidHideNotification"
                                           object:dict];
```

and :

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    // move the view up by 30 pts
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -kbSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];
}

- (void) keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)note {

    // move the view back to the origin
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

But those two methods is not working when the keyboard is showing up or hiding.
And those two methods is working if I pass object nil, instead dict.

I don't know where is the problem, please help me , Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I can see you are trying to post object at observer side. It is quite opposite, see the example below.

Receiver class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"myNotification"
        object:nil];
}

- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"myNotification"]) {
        NSDictionary *myDictionary = (NSDictionary *)notification.object;
        //doSomething here.
    }
}
```

Sender Class

```
- (void)sendNotification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:YOUR_DICTIONARY];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `object` parameter is designed to specify the particular object to observe, not for passing arbitrary data to the called selector.

From the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:):

> `notificationSender`
>
> The object whose notifications the observer wants
>   to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are
>   delivered to the observer.
>
> If you pass `nil`, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s
>   sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I pass my those parameters ?

Comment: @UyghurBoy You should store them in an instance variable.

Comment: @UyghurBoy Actually it's unclear exactly how they should be passed as it depends on how they are used (i.e. do they change from one moment to the next).  Therefore it might be better to determine their value within the called selector or store them in an instance variable.  However I cannot tell you exactly without more information.

Comment: @UyghurBoy I would argue that my answer explained what was happening and the other answer solved a different question, that you did not ask.

Comment: sorry, maybe I am not good at explaining, but I hope I can pass parameters.